# Update user in parse cloud

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i'm using parse cloud code to update the user informations using this code below:

```
var SaveObject = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
  var saveObject = new Parse.Query(SaveObject);
  saveObject.equalTo("username", "sam");
  saveObject.first({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(Objects) {
      Objects.save(null, {
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function(object) {
          object.set("foo":"bar");
          object.save();
          response.success('SUCCESS');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

but i still getting the error in php sdk

```
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: result in <b>/php/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseCloud.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />
```

**Note: i tried every answer that has been posted regard to parse cloud code on here, i couldn't find any answer that can solve this problem.**

Comment: Please go in small steps. What's the output of the first callback, i.e. what happens after `saveObject.first()`? Then what happens after the second callback?

Comment: @Jost after first callback same error

Comment: Which version Parse are you using? The current API uses promises, so try `saveObject.first({useMasterKey: true}).then(objects => console.log(objects)).catch(error => console.error(error));`